# GLSL texelFetch Compile Error

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I have a small amount of code I've had tons of trouble compiling. I'm hoping someone can point out what is wrong here.

Setting up my texture buffer for rendering:

```
glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE0 + 1 );
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, transformsUniform );
glTexBuffer( GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, GL_RGBA32F, transformBuffer );
glUniform1i( transformBufferTexture, 1 );
```

Accessing the buffer with texelFetch:

```
uniform samplerBuffer transforms;
...
vec4 v( texelFetch( transforms, 0 ) );
```

Exact compiler error:

```
ERROR: 0:10: error(#132) Syntax error: "texelFetch" parse error
ERROR: error(#273) 1 compilation errors.  No code generated
```

I already checked my shader language version with `glGetString( GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION );` and it said `4.2`, so that's not the problem.

Comment: Do you have a `#version` directive in your shader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GLSL doesn't support C++-style initialization with the syntax you used:

```
vec4 v( texelFetch( transforms, 0 ) );
```

Instead, simply use the assignment operator:

```
vec4 v = texelFetch( transforms, 0 );
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
vec4 v = texelFetch( transforms, 0 );
```

The "standard" C++-style inline declaration/construction you're trying to do is forbidden by the GLSL spec, see the `declaration:` grammar definition on [page 171](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.4.20.11.clean.pdf):

```
declaration:
    function_prototype SEMICOLON
    init_declarator_list SEMICOLON
    PRECISION precision_qualifier type_specifier SEMICOLON
    type_qualifier IDENTIFIER LEFT_BRACE struct_declaration_list RIGHT_BRACE SEMICOLON
    type_qualifier IDENTIFIER LEFT_BRACE struct_declaration_list RIGHT_BRACE IDENTIFIER SEMICOLON
    type_qualifier IDENTIFIER LEFT_BRACE struct_declaration_list RIGHT_BRACE IDENTIFIER LEFT_BRACKET RIGHT_BRACKET SEMICOLON
    type_qualifier IDENTIFIER LEFT_BRACE struct_declaration_list RIGHT_BRACE IDENTIFIER LEFT_BRACKET constant_expression RIGHT_BRACKET SEMICOLON
    type_qualifier SEMICOLON
    type_qualifier IDENTIFIER SEMICOLON
    type_qualifier IDENTIFIER identifier_list SEMICOLON
```